# How to reference external library in Jenkins project

Tags: continuous-integration, assemblies, jenkins

I've having issues with Jenkins CI when I try to build a project that I've created. The project is a VS2010 C# project that compiles and runs correctly on my machine, but when I commit it to the SVN server and try to build it in Jenkins, I get errors that say it cannot find a type or namespace that is used in my project (in this case, it's Lead Tools which is the offending library). I know the Lead Tools .dll files are located in a folder inside the main solution's folder on SVN, so they do exist. I also know that the Lead Tools assemblies are properly referenced in the solution since it compiles and runs correctly on my machine. Is it possible that the reference to those assemblies was lost somehow in committing the solution and trying to build from Jenkins? Is there a way I can re-add the reference if this is the case? I would post the build output here, but it's absolutely massive. The error message I get says:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Leadtools' could not be found (are you
missing a using directive or an assembly reference? E:\Jenkins\Workspace\path\to\project\project.csproj)
```

I apologize if this question is vague, but I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your Jenkins, build your project? is it using ANT or any other build tool to build your project?? if you are using ANT, you can specify it in CLASSPATH variable. if you are using any other build tool, then you should probably search on how to supply dependencies to your build tool, since your project requires dependencies(in your case LeadTools) to compile.

find where your LeadTools(probably class) is, and supply that path in your buildtool,if your build tool is ANT

then you can provide classpath like this in your build.xml

```
    <classpath>
      <pathelement path="${classpath}"/>
      <pathelement location="lib/LeadTools.jar"/>
    </classpath>
```

Comment: I'm using MSBuild for this project. By chance do you know anything about supplying a dependency to MSBuild? I'll try to search for information on that now. Thanks!